# Using structs to compare strings

Tags: c

```
typdef struct{
    int year;
    char* make;
    char* model;
    int miles;
}Car;

int equals(Car* car, int year, char* make, char* model)
{
   if(strcmp(car->make,make)==0 && strcmp(car->model,model==0))
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

void drive_cars(Car *garage, int* num_cars,char* driving_records)
{
   int i,size1,j,k;
   FILE* file=fopen(driving_records,"r");
   fscanf(file,"%d",&size1);
   Car update[size1];
   for(i=0;i<size1;i++)
   {
      fscanf(file,"%d%s%s%d",&update[i].year,&update[i].make,&update[i].model,&update[i].miles);
   }

   for(j=0;j<*num_cars;j++)
   {
      for(k=0;k<size1;k++)
      {
         if(equals(&garage[j],update[k].year,update[k].make,update[k].model)==1)
         {
            garage[j].miles=garage[j].miles+update[k].miles;
         }
      }
   }

   fclose(file);
}

void store_car_statistics(Car* garage, int num_cars, char* outFile)
{
   int i;
   FILE* file=fopen(outFile,"w");
   for(i=0;i<num_cars;i++)
   {
      fprintf(file,"%d %s %s %d\n",garage[i].year,garage[i].make,garage[i]    .model,garage[i].miles);
   }
   fclose(file);
}
```

This code is for comparing the year, make, and model to a struct that contains an array of car year makes and model. The function gets passed the address of one of the Car structs, a year from a different struct that contains update information,the address of a struct that has different makes, and the address of a struct that has different models. Then if they are equal it updates the miles with the changes. However I keep getting seg faults when I try to run the code.

Comment: Hint: put spaces in your code. like this `for(i = 0; i < num_cars; i++)` it will facilitate other people reading your programming.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that it keeps seg faulting at the end of my question.

Comment: Remove the line numbers please...

Comment: @Almo I wish I could uptick your comment +10 instead of just +1. :)

Comment: use a debugger to find where the segfault occurs

Comment: The most common causes of a segfault are either (a) not allocating memory for a pointer that you're using, or (b) writing more data to a buffer/array than you have allocated. Read through your code and check for those cases.

Comment: the seg fault occurs at the fscanf in the loop in the drive_cars function

Comment: I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here

Comment: The first 'if' statement has unbalanced parentheses. It doesn't compile.

Comment: How is `Car` defined? Are the `model` and `make` members just pointers? If so, they need to be allocated (see my prior comment). And you wouldn't `scanf` for `&update[i].model`, you would just use `update[i].model` in that case. Same for `make`. Please show your `Car` structure.

Comment: @KeithSmith it compiles

Comment: I have already tried changing model and make without the address operator and it still seg faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `make` and `model` members are `char *` and have not been allocated when you attempt to `fscanf` them in. That is, `update[i].make` and `update[i].model` are undefined pointers to `char`. You need to allocate them with `malloc`. Note you need to have space for a terminating null for strings, thus the `+ 1`:

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<size1;i++)
{
    update[i].make = malloc(<size of the make string you need + 1>);
    update[i].model = malloc(<size of the model string you need + 1>);
    fscanf(file, "%d%s%s%d", &update[i].year, update[i].make, update[i].model, &update[i].miles);
}
```

And do not use the address of (`&`) the `char *` items (which is the address of the pointer), as shown above.

As Peter Schneider points out in the comments, you could also just define your `struct` using statically allocated members:

```
typdef struct{
    int year;
    char make[MAX_MAKE_LEN+1];
    char model[MAX_MODEL_LEN+1];
    int miles;
} Car;
```

And given the amount of data you likely have, this is a perfectly reasonable approach. It's good, though, to learn good dynamic memory management techniques for scalability.

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson `update` is an array, but `model` and `make` are *pointers* inside of *each* `struct` and must be allocated. `update[i].model` and `update[i].make` are undefined pointers in your code.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are on a machine where a few bytes more or less wouldn't matter and if you can produce sensible upper limits for model and make (which is likely), you could just define char arrays inside the struct. That would make freeing the malloc'ed arrays unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterSchneider indeed. The strings are probably short and the array of structs is probably not large enough to worry about statically defining the arrays.